# "New diagnosed" vs. "newly diagnosed"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, adjectives, adverbs

Which one of the following is correct to use?

> - *New* diagnosed cases.
> - *Newly* diagnosed cases.

Answer (score 10):

- New diagnosed cases - "New" is an adjective, which qualifies the noun "cases".  So this means that the cases themselves are new.  They also happen to have been diagnosed.
- Newly diagnosed cases - "Newly" is an adverb, which qualifies the verb "diagnosed".  So this means that the cases themselves may or may not be new; but they have only just been diagnosed.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on which meaning you want.  *New diagnosed cases* suggests that they are diagnosed cases that you haven't yet seen. *Newly diagnosed cases* suggests that they are cases that have just been diagnosed, regardless of whether you have or haven't seen them.